# Firefox-Developer-Tools - network tab - images - What means 'imageset' & 'vendors-main.chunk' in column 'initiator'

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

I have a  set with webp and jpg files as alternative images for incompatible browsers.

Do I understand correctly that in the column "Initiator" the entry "imageset" means the loaded image and "vendor-main.chunk..." means the alternative image?

I have inspected the DOM element and it shows me under current source that the webp image is being loaded correctly.

Both have the status 200.

Will the alternative image still be loaded, even if the browser uses the webp image?

Here are 2 Screens from the DevTools:

[image: DevTools - Network overview - webp]

[image: DevTools - Network overview - jpg]

edit 1:
Here is some jsx (react) code for selecting the appropriate image:

```
<ImgContainer>
<ImgItem animate={animationImg1}>
    <picture>
        // if the browser support webp images
        <source srcSet={img1Webp} type="image/webp" alt="Praxis Hauptraum" />

        // if the browser does not support webp images
        <source srcSet={img1Jpg} type="image/jpeg" alt="Praxis Hauptraum" />

        // Fallback if the browser does not support the picture tag
        <img src={img1Jpg} alt="Praxis Hauptraum" />
    </picture>
</ImgItem>
....
```

edit 2: screenshot showing the images on the site:

[image: Screenshot from the site]

edit 3: Screenshot from Dom of the section "Praxis". This Section contains 3 images as picture tags.

[image: DOM Element Structure]

Comment: Hi kinglycodes! You should also post a screenshot of the DOM element to make it clearer how the image is meant to be loaded.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I have updated my first post, added code example and a screen from the site.

Comment: Thank you for adding the JSX code and the screenshot of the page! It seems I wasn't clear enough regarding "screenshot of the DOM element". I meant a screenshot of the DevTools Inspector panel showing the DOM element structure. Nonetheless, I'll try to answer your question as good as I can with the given information.

Comment: Also, what happens if you remove the line with `<source srcSet={img1Jpg} type="image/jpeg" alt="Praxis Hauptraum" />`? Is the request for the JPEG image then gone?

Comment: Thank you Sebastian for the fast answer and the description. Now I understand it a bit clearer.

When removing the suggested line, nothing change in the network tab. It still loads the jpg and the webp image.

Comment: Ok, that means the request for the JPEG image is independent of the URL provided in the `<source>` element and it must come from somewhere else. As I mentioned in my answer, the request is triggered by some JavaScript, i.e. it is probably generated by the code behind the `<ImgItem>` or `<ImgContainer>` elements. Also, again, it might provide a little more info if you also posted a screenshot of the final DOM structure shown in the Inspector.

Comment: It would also be interesting to see what's on main.chunk.js:1:89. I've adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: updated the main post, added image of DOM element structure.

Comment: I don't know, how to open the main.chunk.js file in the debugger. Double click on the line opens the image in a new tab. Single click on the main.chunk.js opens the detail view with the tabs header, cookies, stack trace ...

Comment: Thank you for adding the screenshot of the Inspector! In the screenshot you can see that there are some event handlers attached to the `<source>` and `<image>` elements.

To open the file in the Debugger you have to click the last entry within the *Stack Trace* side panel. Alternatively, you can switch to the Debugger panel and search for the file in there. Then you can check what's in line one and line 25114.

Answer (score 0):

"imageset" in the *Initiator* column basically means an image loaded from a given set of images to choose from defined within HTML. In your case it means via `<source srcSet="..." />` in your `<picture>` elements.

"vendors~main.chunk.js" in that column means the related image got loaded through a JavaScript call. The request for that image happens on line 25114 of that script.

So both requests obviously happen independently from each other and the one caused by the script is redundant.

In order to find out what exactly is causing the request to the JPEG image, you need to click the last line in the call stack (main.chunk.js:1:89). That switches to the Debugger where you can see what statement is the origin of the request. (You may want to pretty-print that script.)
From that line you can step into the function calls that lead to the request.